# MSDTC - how many ports are needed

Tags: firewall, msdtc, ports

I have a considerably large application that uses MSDTC. How many ports should I open? Is there any way to determine it?

**EDIT:** I know **what** ports I need to open, I don't know **how many** I need.

Comment: This is not offensive. Probably the users downvoted and marking offensive don't know what MSDTC is!

Comment: Whoever is marking offensive: PLEASE read the FAQ- if it's not hate speech, spam, or full of curse words use CLOSE not offensive.

Comment: Perhaps this is more of a Serverfault.com question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Migol wants to know how big the range of the [RPC dynamic port allocation](http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?kbid=154596) should be.

In the KB they mention a minimum of 100 ports

> Furthermore, previous experience shows
>   that a minimum of 100 ports should be
>   opened, because several system
>   services rely on these RPC ports to
>   communicate with each other.

So I would design a benchmark application to test different values of your dynamic range.

Answer (score 9):

When we've had to do this kind of debugging this article has been especially useful:
[How to troubleshoot MS DTC firewall issues](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306843).  It includes an app called DTCPing which helps you to rapidly debug what the problem is.

As far as I remember the following ports were used:

TCP Port 1433 (Default port used by SQL Server)

UDP Port 1434 (Used by SQL Server)

TCP Port 3372 (Used by MSDTC.EXE)

Comment: 1434 Is for SQL Browser